# Memory leak with runtime polymorphism

Tags: memory-leaks, fortran, polymorphism, language-lawyer, gfortran

While tracking down unexpected large memory consumption of our code I think I found a bug in gfortran which I could reproduce with versions 7.5.0, 9.4.0, and 10.3.0.
The error does not appear in ifort 19.1.1.217.

In summary:
If a factory function returns an allocatable (not a pointer) instance of a virtual class, then it is apparently not correctly destroyed, when it should be.

This applies to cases, where (1) the result is used in an expression and should be immediately deleted, or (2) the result is assigned to a variable of `class(...), allocatable` type and the variable is allocated via automatic allocation upon assignment.

The following minimal examples demonstrate the problem.
In my understanding all these examples should work. So my question is two-fold:
Is it actually standard-conforming code, or does it fail because of my coding error? How should I use runtime-polymorphism in practice if this does not work?

All examples use the following module file

```
module shapes_mod
    implicit none
    private
    public :: Shape_t, Rectangle_t, Circle_t, PI, get_shape, get_volume

    real, parameter :: PI = atan(1.0) * 4.0

    type, abstract :: Shape_t
    contains
        procedure(get_area_t), deferred :: get_area
    end type

    abstract interface
        elemental real function get_area_t(this)
            import :: Shape_t
            class(Shape_t), intent(in) :: this
        end function
    end interface

    type, extends(Shape_t) :: Circle_t
        real :: r
    contains
        procedure :: get_area => get_area_Circle_t
    end type

    type, extends(Shape_t) :: Rectangle_t
        real :: a, b
    contains
        procedure :: get_area => get_area_Rectangle_t
    end type

    contains

    elemental function get_area_Circle_t(this) result(res)
        class(Circle_t), intent(in) :: this
        real :: res
        res = this%r**2 * PI
    end function

    elemental function get_area_Rectangle_t(this) result(res)
        class(Rectangle_t), intent(in) :: this
        real :: res
        res = this%a * this%b
    end function

    pure function get_shape(arg1, arg2) result(res)
        !! Contrived constructor, that gives a circle for one and a rectangle for two arguments.
        real, intent(in) :: arg1
        real, intent(in), optional :: arg2
        class(Shape_t), allocatable :: res
        if (present(arg2)) then
            res = Rectangle_t(arg1, arg2)
        else
            res = Circle_t(arg1)
        end if
    end function

    elemental function get_volume(base, h) result(res)
        !! Get the volume of a prism of the 2D shape base and height h.
        class(Shape_t), intent(in) :: base
        real, intent(in) :: h
        real :: res
        res = h * base%get_area()
    end function

end module
```

The following program works correctly as expected:

```
program main
    use shapes_mod, only: Shape_t, Rectangle_t, Circle_t, get_shape, get_volume
    implicit none

    block
        integer :: i
        integer, parameter :: n = 4
        real, allocatable :: volumes(:)
        allocate(volumes(N))
        do i = 1, n
            if (mod(i, 2) == 0) then
                volumes(i) = get_volume(Rectangle_t(1., 2.), 5.)
            else
                volumes(i) = get_volume(Circle_t(2.), 5.)
            end if
        end do
        write(*, *) volumes
    end block
end program
```

The following program uses a temporary `class, allocatable` variable.
When running with `valgrind` I get `Invalid write of size 4` and `Invalid write of size 8`.

```
program main
    use shapes_mod, only: Shape_t, Rectangle_t, Circle_t, get_shape, get_volume
    implicit none

    block
        integer :: i
        integer, parameter :: n = 4
        real, allocatable :: volumes(:)
        class(Shape_t), allocatable :: shape
        allocate(volumes(N))
        do i = 1, n
            if (mod(i, 2) == 0) then
                shape = Rectangle_t(1., 2.)
            else
                shape = Circle_t(3.)
            end if
            volumes(i) = get_volume(shape, 5.)
        end do
        write(*, *) volumes
    end block
end program
```

The next example uses the result of factory function directly without assignment.
This example is closest to our actual problem in our large code.
It does memory leak and if the system size parameter `n` is high enough, one eventually runs out of memory (confirmed with `valgrind`).

```
program main
    use shapes_mod, only: Shape_t, Rectangle_t, Circle_t, get_shape, get_volume
    implicit none

    block
        integer :: i
        integer, parameter :: n = 20
        real, allocatable :: volumes(:)
        allocate(volumes(N))
        do i = 1, n
            if (mod(i, 2) == 0) then
                volumes(i) = get_volume(get_shape(1., 2.), 5.)
            else
                volumes(i) = get_volume(get_shape(2.), 5.)
            end if
        end do
        write(*, *) volumes
    end block
end program
```

Comment: It is not against the standard for a processor to defer releasing storage of a function result.

Comment: @francescalus This may be right, but although not a bug per se, this is an implementation flaw when it results in memory overflow.

Comment: On https://godbolt.org/ I could reproduce the problem even with latest version of gfortran. ifort/ifx do well. This does not prove that the code is standard conforming, though.

Comment: @PierU, I'm quite happy to call a deficient quality of implementation an actual bug, but with [tag:language-lawyer] QoI is not really the issue.

Comment: I added the language-lawyer tag, because I did not trust myself enough to be sure, that it is fully standard-conforming, correct code. Hence I left the possibility open, that it is just faulty code that leads to this memory leak.

Comment: It seems that your code is actually not [standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf) conforming: *"C1585 The function result of a pure function shall not be both polymorphic and allocatable, or have a polymorphic allocatable ultimate component"* . Both gfortran and ifort are more permissive than the standard here. That said, removing the pure attribute to the `get_shape` function does not fix the problem in gfortran

Comment: The release of the storage can indeed be deferred and done by, e.g., a Boehm garbage collector. However, ignoring all deallocations and deferring them to the moment of the ultimate cleanup done by the OS when the program exits is somewhat extreme. It certainly would not be the first memory leak bug with polymorphic stuff in gfortran. I actually suggest to search the Bugzilla because the likelihood of finding it reported there is quite high.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug that's already reported, but I'm not in a good place to check now.  Certainly I've run into very similar.

Comment: OK, is it the same as https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60913 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around for some time and incorporating some of the comments given, I think I solved the problem.
Thanks to @PierU, @Vladimir F Героям слава, @Ian Bush for their comments!
What was still missing from the comments was a reasonably clean workaround.
Hence I will write my own answer now.
If there are better ones, I am happy to accept them instead.

## Standard conformance

As pointed out by @PierU, pure functions may not return polymorphic allocatables and pure subroutines may not have them as `intent(out)` arguments. That is good to know, but did not fix the problem.

It is actually a bug in `gfortran` as found by @IanBush [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60913).

## Automatic deallocation

The first example where one gets `Invalid write of size 4` and `Invalid write of size 8` in `valgrind` is fixed, if one adds an explicit deallocation.
So it has to become

```
! ...
volumes(i) = get_volume(shape, 5.)
deallocate(shape)
```

## Factory subroutine

Using a factory subroutine and giving the `shape`  a name instead of reusing the result in an expression solves then the problem.

```
program main
    use shapes_mod, only: Shape_t, Rectangle_t, Circle_t, get_shape, get_volume
    implicit none

    block
        integer :: i
        integer, parameter :: n = 20
        real, allocatable :: volumes(:)
        class(Shape_t), allocatable :: shape
        allocate(volumes(N))
        do i = 1, n
            if (mod(i, 2) == 0) then
                call construct_shape(shape, 1., 2.)
            else
                call construct_shape(shape, 3.)
            end if
            volumes(i) = get_volume(shape, 5.)
        end do
        write(*, *) volumes
    end block

contains

    subroutine construct_shape(shape, arg1, arg2)
        !! Contrived constructor, that gives a circle for one and a rectangle for two arguments.
        class(Shape_t), allocatable, intent(out) :: shape
        real, intent(in) :: arg1
        real, intent(in), optional :: arg2
        if (present(arg2)) then
            shape = Rectangle_t(arg1, arg2)
        else
            shape = Circle_t(arg1)
        end if
    end subroutine
end program
```

Note that `shape` is of `intent(out), allocatable` in the factory subroutine, so it is automatically deallocated. (This now actually works in the gfortran implementation.)
So the explicit deallocation is not required.

With this code it cleanly passes valgrind.